# haml - erb filter inside table cell pushes text outside (in the markup)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Haml is rending my html incorrectly with an erb filter.  Any ideas how to get it to generate the correct markup?

This haml markup generates the following HTML

HAML:

```
%table
  %tbody
    -items.each do |foo|
      %tr
        %td       
          %div
            :erb
              (<strong><%= foo.name %></strong>)
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<strong>bar</strong>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td><div></div></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Gem Info

haml (3.1.4)

haml-rails (0.3.5)

Comment: It works ok for me. How are you viewing the generated html – in a browser? Do the parenthese not appear at all in the generated code?

Answer (score 1):

Does it make a difference if you replace this:

```
:erb
  (<strong><%= foo.name %></strong>)
```

with:

```
%span
  (%strong= foo.name)
```

Comment: That does stop it from moving the markup/content outside of the table, but still doesn't format it the way I intended

Comment: What does the HTML look like now? What kind of format do you need?

Comment: I need it to render as (<strong>bar</strong>)

Comment: You mean the parentheses? Do this `%strong (#{foo.name})` Is that what you need?

Comment: I don't want the parentheses to inside the strong tag.  Its not something that should be haml, it should be in an erb filter.

Comment: What if you add a span like my edited answer? See if that helps. If you don't like the span, just having `(%strong= foo.name)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question -- and I can't replicate the error the op is having -- but if anyone else is having a similar error and needs a solution, haml now supplies a helper #surround.

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#surround-instance_method

So for this problem, it would look something like:

```
= surround '(', ')' do
  %strong #{foo.name}
```